# How can I use `requires` directive with specific rpm release in Nebula ospackage?

Tags: java, gradle, require, nebula

I used it in gradle build script like as

```
requires('iptables', '1.4.21', LESS | EQUAL)
```

but I want to use it like as

```
requires('iptables', '1.4.21-24.1.el7_5', LESS | EQUAL)
```

Is there any way?